# Android Managed Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to make my Android app publicly available on Google Play Store.
I recently noticed that Managed Google Play is active for said app and cannot be disabled.I figured out the only way of disabling Managed Google Play is simply creating another app which won't do the job since Managed Google Store is enabled by default.

My question is: Will an enabled managed google play app be available on store on production track?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Looking through this thread and being positive about "google-play-console" tag being existent i am figuring out my question is indeed on topic.